# Difficulties to use columnspan

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1, columnspan

I have  grid with four texboxs like these :

[image: What I have]

And I would to get this:

[image: What I want]

I have tried to play with column span but with no success :(

```
<Grid Margin="20,0,0,20" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition />                                           
    <RowDefinition />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<TextBlock  Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,10,0" x:Name="TxtBox_CodeTiers" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding m_strCode}"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="23"/>
<TextBlock  Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,10,0" x:Name="TxtBox_NomTiers" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding m_strNom}"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="23" />
<TextBlock  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,05,0" x:Name="TxtBox_CPostal" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding m_strCpostal}"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
<TextBlock  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,05,0" x:Name="TxtBox_Ville" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding m_strVille}"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
</Grid>
```

It better with this :)

```
<Grid Margin="12,0,0,20" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition />                                           
    <RowDefinition />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  x:Name="TxtBox_CodeTiers" Margin="0,0,20,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding m_strCode}"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="23" Loaded="TxtBlock_Loaded"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  x:Name="TxtBox_NomTiers" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding m_strNom}"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="23" Loaded="TxtBlock_Loaded"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  x:Name="TxtBox_CPostal" Margin="0,0,20,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding m_strCpostal}"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" Loaded="TxtBlock_Loaded"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="TxtBox_Ville" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding m_strVille}"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"  Loaded="TxtBlock_Loaded"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Use two `<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">` inside of a regular `<StackPanel>` instead of a `Grid`. Grids are meant to be used for laying out controls in a tabular way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to add another column for the "C" and "D" boxes to line up against, then just set the `ColumnSpan` on the "A" box to span the new column

```
  <Grid Margin="20,0,0,20" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="121*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="52*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="190*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  x:Name="TxtBox_CodeTiers" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="AAAAAAAAA"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="23"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  x:Name="TxtBox_NomTiers" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="BBBBBBBB"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="23" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  x:Name="TxtBox_CPostal" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="CCCCCCCCCCC"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="TxtBox_Ville" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="DDDDDDDDD"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"  />
    </Grid>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! I added the solution (with your help) on my question ! Nevertheless i don't know what is the difference between using margin or columnDefinition widht="" in my case !

Comment: Margin sets the distance from the edges of the "cells", eg: Margin="5" will set the textblock 5 pixels from each side of the column/row

Answer (score 0):

You can use in the second grid row `StackPanel`:

```
<Grid Margin="20,0,0,20" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock  Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,10,0" x:Name="TxtBox_CodeTiers" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding m_strCode}"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="23"/>
    <TextBlock  Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,10,0" x:Name="TxtBox_NomTiers" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding m_strNom}"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="23" />      
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,05,0" x:Name="TxtBox_CPostal" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding m_strCpostal}"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,05,0" x:Name="TxtBox_Ville" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding m_strVille}"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```